# RegLoadKey and RegUnLoadKey - how to force unload if handles are open?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I have a simple win32 app that mounts a registry hive, adds a key to it and then unloads it.

Sample is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL EnablePrivilege(LPCTSTR tszPrivilege, BOOL bEnable)
{
    DWORD  dwStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;


    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, tszPrivilege, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    }


    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    if (bEnable)
    {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    }
    else
    {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
    }


    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return FALSE;
    };


    CloseHandle(hToken);

    return TRUE;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (!EnablePrivilege(SE_RESTORE_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        std::cout << "Enable priv failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (!EnablePrivilege(SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        std::cout << "Enable priv failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Load /create hive
    auto err = ::RegLoadKey(HKEY_USERS, L"HiveTesting", L"Testing.hive");
    if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "LoadKey fail " << err << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a key in the loaded hive
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    ::RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_USERS, L"HiveTesting\\Testing", 0, 0, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hKey, 0);
    ::RegCloseKey(hKey);


    err = ::RegUnLoadKey(HKEY_USERS, L"HiveTesting");
    if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "UnLoadKey fail " << err << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected unless I'm looking at the loaded hive in regedit. This is because regedit keeps a handle to one of the keys open. This makes RegUnLoadKey key fail with error 5 / ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

However in my application I must unload the hive file no matter what - is there a way to force the hive to unload at this point? I suspect deleting the keys may work as this would cause regedit to get ERROR_KEY_DELETED when using the handle. But even if this did work I don't want to nuke all of my data. Also RegSaveKey performs much worse than RegLoad/RegUnLoad APIs.

Comment: Hmya, "How can I crash the other program instead," is a pretty common question.  It of course has no answer, the ability to arbitrarily crash other processes is not an OS feature.  And is a security nightmare, handle recycle attacks can cause enormous damage.

Comment: Well a key can be deleted while an application has a handle to it, so why can't I unload it?

Comment: It would appear "the system" was designed by an 8 headed beast